# Google Spreadsheet - app script - onOpen function runs only ca. 50%

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have written this script for Spreadsheet:

```
function onOpen() {    
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My - Menue')
      .addItem('Menue auf Deutsch','DescGerman')
      .addItem('Menue in English','DescEnglish')
      .addToUi();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

The script is running and create the menue - but no more. The second part from my menue will not run an so i don´t get a new Trigger.

Does anyone knows or have a tipp for me where is my probleme?

Comment: Are you deleting the On Change triggers that are being created?  If not, there are probably many, many triggers in whatever spreadsheet this code is running in.  In the code editor, click "Edit" menu, and "Current project's triggers."  How many triggers by that same name are there?

Comment: Did you try to run this function in the script editor? Does it run without any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I updated you code in the sheet. Now a second sheet will append a timestamp every time a change is made because a trigger is installed. The trigger was installed by clicking on the menu item DescGerman. Hope this is helpful.

```
function onOpen() {    
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My - Menue')
      .addItem('Menue auf Deutsch','DescGerman')
      .addItem('Menue in English','DescEnglish')
      .addToUi();
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {google.script.run.nextCode();
});
}

function DescGerman(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
  }

function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tabellenblatt2')
  var time = new Date
  sheet.appendRow([time])
}
```

Comment: Hello, now we have a new week with a brain-reset. Now I check it - thanks thanks thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to run a script that needs permission before the app is initialised (the SpreadsheetApp class and the ScriptApp class will cause this). 
Try something different like this.

**Let the menu do it's thing**

```
function onOpen() {    
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My - Menue')
      .addItem('Menue auf Deutsch','DescGerman')
      .addItem('Menue in English','DescEnglish')
      .addToUi();
}
```

**In the sidebar**

Then when the side bar/dialogue whatever open call and then call the next script.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  google.script.run.nextCode();
});
```

**In the Code.gs**

```
  function nextCode(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
  }
```

Comment: Hello, i´m standing complete on the line. Is it OK when you add the my missing part here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1doUe5mZOWOoH8aLzAe24T5xgwqr9QMX82PrpIDUhbxk/edit?usp=sharing